# Some tag proposals

Tags: discussion, tags

### Open questions

- I think a general principle to follow is that most tags shouldn't have "language" or "conlang" in them. Exceptions would be when it's explicitly distinguishing conlang and natlangs, or when there's already a set phrase with "language" in it. [Language change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_change) is one such example, so the [language-change](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change) tag for questions on natural developments of conlangs is appropriate.
- We've had a few questions about what is required to be a "complete" language. I'm not sure what a good tag could be for those. Idea: what about [conlang-mvp](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-mvp)? Too cute?

---

### What we've settled on (though feel free to still contest these tags)

- For questions on conlangs changing over time, [we have decided on](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/63/113) both [language-change](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change) and [diachronics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diachronics).
- And what about a tag [unnatural-features](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unnatural-features) for questions about designing conlang features with no parallels in natural languages?
- We probably need to better distinguish between [typology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typology) and [classification](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification).
- What do we want for [tags about writing systems](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/50/113)? [writing-systems](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems)
- Having both phrase and single word requests at ELU is a mess. Lets simplify things from the beginning, and have a single tag: [phrase-requests](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests).
- The [texts](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texts) tag is a meta tag, and I don't see how it would be useful to have. I'd say we burn it.

  - For questions like [the one on the Lord's Prayer](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/207/why-is-the-lords-prayer-so-common-as-a-translation), what about a tag like [conlang-promotion](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-promotion)?
- [conlang-history](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-history) can probably just be [history](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) - we're not here to discuss world history! I'd include in this tag both the history of constructed languages as a discipline, as well as key moments in the development of particular languages,  from the human side of development, though not for questions about the development of languages themselves, which should be [language-change](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change). [history](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) for questions about people, [language-change](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change) for questions about languages themselves, if that makes sense.
- [words](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) seems like a pretty useless tag. Can anyone make a case for it?

  Maybe [vocabulary-development](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary-development) for questions like these?

  - [Methods to avoid similarity in lexicons](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/323/113)
  - [What's a good starting place to work on vocab?](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/459/113)

  I renamed it to [vocabulary](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary).

Comment: I don't think we need [typology] at all; anything it might be used on could already have [classification] or [terminology].

Comment: @CHEESE We'll have to see which questions get asked, but I'm sure there will be ones which won't fit either classification or terminology. Questions asking for an explanation of natlang typology and how it can be adapted to conlangs for example.

Comment: I find that diachronics is used wrongly here. A better name would be condiachronics or similar--diachronics refers to language with the focus on language change.

Answer (score 6):

Writing a new answer because I’ve thought a bit more about the whole thing. Here’s my proposed solution:

1. For questions related to a specific well-known language, always use a language-specific tag, e.g. [tolkien-sindarin](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-sindarin). Don’t tag your own project that no one has heard of like that though. Don’t use any -language or -conlang suffixes for these, that’s just redundant. E.g. [klingon](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon) not [klingon-language](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klingon-language)

   a. For questions about how such a conlang was developed, changed during its development, and also how it was received or adapted by learners, [conlang-history](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-history) seems appropriate as an additional tag.
2. For questions about how to make a conlang, I suggest [conlang-creation](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-creation).

   a. For questions which are relevant to a specific subfield of linguistics, additional tags such as [phonology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology) would be appropriate.

   b. I would also like to emphasize that simulating natural language change is a thing that some conlangers do, here [diachronics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diachronics) is particularly appropriate.
3. Various questions regarding conlanging terminology can take a [terminology](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag, and similarly for classification stuff there can be [classification](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification)
4. Questions about creating scripts (including stuff like making fonts) get [neography](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neography), questions about writing in general [writing-systems](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems). Overlap exists, but shouldn’t be cause for worry.

   a. For certain constructed scripts such as Tengwar, specific tags might be appropriate.

   b. What is our opinion on spelling reforms? Are such discussions even on-topic? If yes, [spelling-reform](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling-reform) might be useful. This also in particular relates to projects like [Blisssymbolics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blissymbols) or [Pan-Germanic Logograms](http://cbb.aveneca.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4994) which lie in a grey zone between writing system and conlang but ought to be on-topic here.

Comment: Ah! I think I get what you mean about diachronics now - rather than how speakers of a language change it naturally, do you mean that an author of a conlang used in a story covering hundreds or thousands of years may want to talk about the fictional changes to the language? I think diachronics would be a good tag name for that.

Comment: One issue with neography as a tag is that the term [is used even for scripts like Hangul (Korean)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_script). I don't think we need con- or neo- in front of everything creative on this site, so writing-systems is probably adequate. But lets see what everyone else thinks.

Comment: I'm not convinced of the "conlang" prefix. Seems a bit redundant considering the sites topic.

Answer (score 2):

[language-development](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-development) is an annoyingly ambiguous name. My personal suggestion for tags of this kind would be:

- [lang-creation](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lang-creation) for questions about how to make languages
- [lang-change](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lang-change) or [lang-history](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lang-history) for questions about how conlangs changed over time through revisions seem alright, I don’t see the need to differentiate (and personally would probably favour the latter tag)
- [diachronics](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diachronics) for how *natural languages* change, which is obviously a very different set of questions. Also appropriate here would be questions of the sorts of how native speakers altered a conlang (really only applicable to Esperanto at the moment)

Comment: I could go for language-creation (I don't like shortening it to lang). I think a plain "history" is fine - what other kind of history questions will we get? What kind of natural language diachronic questions would you imagine? Most of those should be asked at Linguistics.SE.

Comment: Or conlang-creation. I just don't really like lang-creation.

Comment: I think we need separate tags for the history of constructed languages as a discipline (including events like the creation of individual conlangs) and for how conlangs have changed over time, either naturally, or through top-down changes from the creator/committee. I'm not sure what would be clear tags for those two things though. I'd prefer a plain "history" for the first, and I think "language-change" might work for the second.

Comment: Either way, I would just like to very clearly separate diachronics. I don’t really see a problem with shortening language to lang, that’s common slang among conlangers. As for language change, diachronic conlanging is absolutely a thing, and so questions on diachronics ought to be on topic. I’ve already asked a questions with that tag myself.

Comment: Mind giving me a link to that question so I can get a better idea of what you mean?

Comment: The tags are clickable, but [here](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-do-tones-disappear-from-a-language) ya go

Comment: @curiousdannii - there are at least three different "histories" when it comes to conlangs: one is the rl history of the creation of the Conlang ("did Tolkien create Quenya before Syndarian?"); other is the rl history of language evolution ("is there something like a Esperanto slang?"), and the third is the con-history of the language ("when did Quenya split from Syndarian?".

Comment: @Luis Yep, and we'd tag them as [tag:history], [tag:language-change], and [tag:diachronics].

Comment: @Luis Maybe a tag *internal-history* for the fictional history of a conlang in its fictional world can be an addition to the tag set, but only a few conlangs I am aware of have a significant internal history worth asking questions about.

Answer (score 2):

TLA's (aka *Three letter acronyms*) aren't good tags (or part of good tags, as in the proposed [conlang-mvp](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conlang-mvp)) because

- Many people don't get them at first sight
- TLA's usually don't have a unique resolution and conflicting usuages might be conflated in one tag
- TLA based tags are hard to suggest: When I am looking for suitable tags for my questions I often enter a "suspicious" substring of the tag and watch the autosuggested tags from the site.

Comment: I agree! Gotta start brainstorming somewhere though.