# Tag proposal 'Script'

Tags: discussion, tags

I am proposing the use of a [script](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/script) or [writing](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing) or anything similar to tag questions that are mainly focused on the script of a language or the analysis thereof.

The need for such a tag formed in my mind when reading [this question on the language of the movie 'Arrival'](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/53/does-the-alien-language-in-arrival-make-sense-can-we-create-custom-sentences).

What are your thoughts on the subject? Would such a tag make sense or promote unnecessary segregation or hordes of other issues?

Comment: Note: If you agree with a proposal you usually upvote it, if you disagree you would downvote it.

Answer (score 3):

We were actually just discussing this [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42750458#42750458). A summary of what was discussed:

- Scripts/writing systems need to be distinguished from how specific languages use them
- Questions on this site are likely to discuss:

  - How existing conlangs are written
  - How to use an existing script for a new conlang
  - How to create a new script
- Possibly all three of these need tags, possibly not.
- Possible tags include: [writing-systems](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems), [orthography](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography), [neography](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neography) (I don't like the last)

Answer (score 0):

There really needs to be a tacit balance between genuine linguistic questions that do not in any way deal with conlanging, and questions about usage in natural languages that do provide some conlanging input. I'm not sure we can ever achieve this balance, nor that we can uncontroversially draw a line between one and the other, but there is and should be a place for questions about how some natural languages use their orthographies.

Comment: "but there is and should be a place for questions about how some natural languages use their orthographies" - yep, that place is [linguistics.se].

Comment: Questions here need to be explicit about their relevance to conlangs.

Comment: A discussion about how East Asian languages use Chinese logographs may be raised in a way that is relevant to conlanging: if someone knowledgeable explains their vital differences, those less knowledgeable might have an easier time devising their own implementation of the script @curiousdannii

Answer (score -1):

I think, there are two things

1. Generic questions about [writing-systems](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems)
2. Specific questions about [conscripts](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conscripts), i.e., constructed writing systems. A conscript can also be used for a natural language (like the Shawian alphabet for English).

Comment: I am not sure if conscript is a good term

Comment: It is at least a somewhat introduced term, see for instance the ConScript Unicode Registry here: http://www.evertype.com/standards/csur/

Comment: I was just trying to make a humorous statement...

Comment: @jknappen It's striking how many of those script names have a K or Z in them!

Comment: @curiousdannii One prolific conscripter seems to be very fond of these two letters

Comment: @jknappen Oh yeah, I didn't notice most of those were by Herman Miller.